# ImportError: No module named model_selection

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to use `train_test_split` function and write:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

and this causes

```
ImportError: No module named model_selection
```

Why? And how to overcome?

Comment: It just occured to me, that you've not accepted any answers in at least your last ten questions. Remember, accepting the most helpful answer will help the answerer and people looking on your question in the future.

Answer (score 193, accepted):

I guess you have the wrong version of `scikit-learn`, a similar situation was described [here on GitHub](https://github.com/alvarouc/mlp/issues/4). Previously (before `v0.18`), `train_test_split` was located in the `cross_validation` module:

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
```

However, now it's in the `model_selection` module:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

so you'll need the newest version.

To upgrade to at least version `0.18`, do:

```
pip install -U scikit-learn
```

*(Or `pip3`, depending on your version of Python). If you've installed it in a different way, make sure you use another method to update, for example when using Anaconda.*

Comment: This didn't work for me, however Farhard Maleki's solution, "conda update scikit-learn" did.

Comment: I ran the pip command you gave, and it would throw an error asking me to upgrade pip. Then I upgraded pip and reran, and it would tell that there was no need to upgrade sklearn, I already have the latest version (0.17) even thought hat wasn't the case. Not trying to haggle, just trying to share info.

Comment: @AlexKinman If you have Python 2 _and_ 3 installed, make sure to use the "right pip" command. Are you sure you don't have venvs or are in the right one? This sounds strange, could you open a Python shell and put in ``import sklearn``, ``sklearn`` (yep, just the word) and ``sklearn.__version__``? Even though it is fixed for you, it would be interesting to know where the issue came from.

Comment: sklearn
Out[2]: <module 'sklearn' from 'C:\Users\XYZ\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.pyc'>

sklearn.__version__
Out[3]: '0.18.2'
*But this is after I've run the Conda upgrade of sklearn*

Comment: Anyhow, good it works for you now. I have not used Anaconda so much, but I guess it does not integrate with pip. Answer edited, all Anaconda users will know :)

Answer (score 26):

Update sklearn:

```sh
conda update scikit-learn
```

Answer (score 9):

I encountered this problem when I import `GridSearchCV`.

Just changed `sklearn.model_selection` to `sklearn.grid_search`.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem while using Jupyter Notebook, no matter what I updated in Python 3, conda, I could not get in Jupyter:

```
import sklearn
print (sklearn.__version__)
0.17.1
```

to SHOW scikit-learn-0.18.1

Finally, I removed Anaconda3 and Jupyter Notebook and reinstalled fresh. I got it to work.

http://ukitech.blogspot.com/2017/02/sklearnmodelselection.html

Answer (score 5):

Do you have sklearn?

If not, do the following:

```
sudo pip install sklearn
```

After installing sklearn:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

works fine.

Answer (score 3):

To install scikit-learn version 18.0, I used both commands:

conda update scikit-learn

pip install -U scikit-learn

But it does not work. There was a problem "Cannot install 'scikit-learn'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall".

Finally, i can install it by using following command:

pip install --user --upgrade scikit-learn==0.18.0

Answer (score 3):

In Late September 2016, SciKit Learn 0.18 was released and there was a slight change to the code. With  SciKit Learn 0.18 the train_test_split function is now imported from model_selection instead of cross_validation.

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
```

has been changed to :

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

The same has also happened for GridSearchCV.

Answer (score 2):

As @linusg said, one option is just import crossvalidation as follows:

```
from sklearn import cross_validation
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.3)
```

Answer (score 2):

Latest Stable release of sklearn 0.20.0 has `train_test_split`  under `model_selection` not under `cross_validation`.

In order to check your sklearn version:

```
import sklearn
print (sklearn.__version__)
0.20.2
```

Answer (score 1):

**Adding some info** to the previous answer from @linusg :

`sklearn` keeps a release history of all its changes. Think of checking it from time to time. [Here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/whats_new.html) is the link to the documentation.

As you can see in the documentation for the version [0.18](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/whats_new.html#version-0-18), a new module was created called `model_selection`. Therefore it didn't exist in previous versions.

Update `sklearn` and it will work !

Answer (score 0):

Your sklearn version is too low, `model_selection` is imported by 0.18.1, so please update the sklearn version.